# How can I get the layout dimensions of a children inside an HOC?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Considering this dummy pieces of code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import styles from './Shadow.style';

const MyHOC = ({children}) => {
   return (
       <View>
         {children}
      </View>
  )
 };

export default MyHOC;
```

How can I get the children's style properties like width, height, borderRadius from the HOC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with that solution:

```
const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState(null);
    return (
     <View
      onLayout={(e) =>
        setDimensions({
          height: e.nativeEvent.layout.height,
          width: e.nativeEvent.layout.width,
        })
      }
  >
  {children}
  </View >
```

So when the children is rendered, the wrapping view set the children dimensions.

Not sure this is the best solution but it works.